# Multiple Drive Letters on a single drive

Tags: windows-8.1

I use an ssd (C:) for my (Windows 8.1) system drive and an hdd (D:) for data, with the library folders redirected to D:.  That works fine, but somehow the D: drive got an extra drive letter (E:) assigned as well, so it shows up twice in File Explorer.  Both entries work, and the contents are identical, so it really is for the same physical drive.  Disk Manager shows only the one drive, labelled D:, but the E: drive letter is unavailable for assignment.

I tried unassigning D: to see if both drive letters would be released, but the system will not allow unassignment of what it considers a system drive.

My system dual boots Windows 10, and the drive assignments are fine there (although of course different, since the system drive changes).

How do I clean this up?

Comment: Is this drive present also after a reboot? Commands such as subst are stopped on a reboot.

Comment: Yes the situation stays the same after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success in these sorts of situations with DISKPART.  From a command prompt, type `diskpart`.  Then, `list volume` to show the available volumes.  Use `select volume <#>` to select the one with D & E. Then, type `remove letter=e`, then `exit`, and close the command prompt.

Comment: If you can't do this from inside windows, (assuming UEFI) you can go into the refresh and reset in settings, boot to advanced and use the command prompt there.

Comment: DISKPART also refused, since the D/E volume had the pagefile on it.  I moved the pagefile back to the ssd (C), rebooted, and tried DISKPART again.  Voila!  It worked!  Thank you very much for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc), find the disk/partition in the lower half of the screen, right-click and select "Change Drive Letter and Paths for :".

In that window it will show all of the listed letters assigned, even if the main window isn't showing it.

To Remove, simply click on the letter, and click remove.

Comment: I tried that, as I said in the original post - Disk Management won't let me change or remove the drive letter of a system drive, which it considers D: to be.

Comment: I guess I was unclear - in that window only D is listed, not E (doing exactly as you suggested).

Answer (score -1):

USBDeview works fine for that. I had a USB using multiple drive letters (4!!!) needed for my hard drives. And if diskpart couldn't do it, this soft did it without breaking a sweat. Quiet amazing USB tool actually. Tons of infos and options in there !

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.